# passing in a String[] and printing it in main statement java

Tags: java, arrays, string, printing

I want to print the result of a method that passes in a `String[]` but I'm getting the error:

```
The method tokenize(String) in the type ReadingScore is not applicable for the arguments (String[])
```

I have this so far:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] arr = {"I", "went", "to", "the", "park", "at", "2:30", "and", "saw", "a", "dog.", "It", "barked!"}; 
        System.out.println(tokenize(arr));
    }
}
```

but I don't understand why it is considering arr as a string

Comment: The error message states that `tokenize` expects a `String` argument, not a `String[]`.

Comment: It isn't. The message is telling you that `tokenize` expects a `String`, but found a String Array, i.e., `String []`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is **exactly because it isn't considering arr as a string**.

The error say that the method `tokenize(String)` expects a `String` as parameter but recived `String[]` (`arr`).

To solve this you can change the variable declaration to it be a `String`:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = "I went to the park at 2:30 and aw a dog It barked!";
    System.out.println(tokenize(str));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The method tokenize(String) expects a String variable as an argument but you are passing tokenize(arr) which is a String array. That is the reason you are getting the error.